# How to remove characters from a pandas series with a condition?

Tags: python, string, pandas, series

I have this series:

```
pokemons=pd.Series(['AlakazamMega Alakazam','BlastoiseMega Blastoise','PinsirMega Pinsir'])
```

I want to delete the duplicate name before 'Mega', so for example the 'BlastoiseMega Blastoise' will become 'Mega Blastoise'.I am working with a much larger series so I need something generally written.

Comment: please add more clearly example, where exists values that shouldn't to be changed.

Comment: So not necessary test values before `Mega` ?

Comment: if name before `Mega` is not a duplicate of surname, you still want to remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use split :

```
short_pokemons = ['Mega'+poke.split('Mega')[1] for poke in pokemons]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) but only for values with equal of both columns of splitted DataFrame:

```
pokemons=pd.Series(['AlakazamMega Alakazam',
                    'BlastoiseMega Blastoise',
                    'StayITHereMega Blastoise'])


df = pokemons.str.split('Mega\s+', expand=True)

pokemons = pokemons.str.replace(r'^.+(Mega)',r'\1').where(df[0] == df[1], pokemons)
print (pokemons)
0               Mega Alakazam
1              Mega Blastoise
2    StayITHereMega Blastoise
dtype: object
```

EDIT:

If need remove all values before `Mega`:

```
pokemons = pokemons.str.replace(r'^.+(Mega)',r'\1')
print (pokemons)
0     Mega Alakazam
1    Mega Blastoise
2    Mega Blastoise
dtype: object
```

Comment: `'StayITHereMega Blastoise'` -- shouldn't to be changed.